# Conditional Drop of a Key based on a test of the Value

Tags: dataset, filtering

I want to restructure a simple dataset.

```
ds = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> "SomeString"|>, <|"a" -> 3, 
"b" -> "SomeOtherString", "c" -> 4|>} // Dataset
```

I want to drop the keys from the individual associates such that I end up with:

```
ds2 = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>} // Dataset
```

I'm sure it can be done with `KeyDrop`, but can't quite figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your example you want to operate based on *values*, not keys, therefore you should not be looking at `KeyDrop`.  Try [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) instead:

```
ds[All, DeleteCases["SomeString" | "SomeOtherString"]]
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>}   (* Dataset *)
> ```

Comment: Urggh! I knew it was going to be obvious in retrospect. Suffering from a case of shiny new function tunnel vision today!